# xelatex can not found fontawesome package

Tags: pdftex

I can use pdflatex compile below example, but xelatex will report error!

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node {\faCamera};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Error message as below:

```
! Package fontspec Error: The font "FontAwesome" cannot be found.
```

What's the reasone xelatex not work with this specific package?

Comment: Problem solved?

Comment: Before you test `\faCamera` inside `tikz` code, better test it in normal text mode.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the syntax is wrong. Try it if it is OK. The node has this syntax:

```
\node[draw] at (0, 0) (a) {\faCamera};
```

---

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw] at (0, 0) (a) {\faCamera};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

PS: This MWE works correctly also with `XeLaTeX`.